# Installing CloudBees SDK and running - Error : cannot create configration

Tags: cloudbees

I have installed the [cloudbees](http://www.cloudbees.com/#slide-1) eclipse plugin and then run the cloudbees project on localhost...but I see this:

```
Installing plugin: org.cloudbees.sdk.plugins:ant-plugin:1.3.0

You have not created a CloudBees configuration profile, let's create one now...
Enter your default CloudBees API end point [us | eu]: us
Enter your CloudBees account email address: abc@abc.com

ERROR: Cannot create configuration
```

kindly guide me how to fix this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download and install cloudbees SDK, so you can try to initialize from command line and maybe get more details on actual (permission ?) issue to write configuration.